# Is there something in the lore that prevents my tiefling from having this skin color?

Tags: dnd-4e, background, tiefling

I'm planning on painting a portrait of my tiefling, so I want to confirm the color I imagine for his skin is possible in the reality dnd 4 is in.
The "base" of his skin would be a pale salmon/peach (something that would *almost* look Caucasian but just enough off to scream "not human skin") and I wanted to add low lights that would lean towards a rusty burgundy color.
The placement of the 'lowlights' would be something like [this](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/buffy/images/3/39/Shells_Illyria_05.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20171227210151) and [this](https://images1.fanpop.com/images/photos/1500000/Illyria-angel-1572940-535-480.jpg). (In case the links don't work, those are reference images of Illyria from the show Angel, showing a distinct blue tint starting mid-forehead and full blue at the hairline.) I imagine his skin growing darker when it gets close to the hairline, in his neck and spidering out from his spine, and on the 'tops' of his limbs, kind of in the same areas where we have the most hair and pigmentations on our arms, etc...

Is that a thing that would be possible on a tiefling? Would it be something that stands out because it would be very rare? (I only have names and jobs of relatives to work with, so I'm free for his backstory. We're paragons by now, so I've had a lot of it built up in my mind but before I lock it all in a painting that'll take me a lot of work, I wanna make sure it makes sense.)

Comment: nobody's answer is great, but personally as a GM, if somebody says 'my tiefling's skin is blue!', my response is basically never going to be "no it isn't", it's going to be "oh cool, do you see that as something common in our world or something that sets them apart?", and going with whatever that player suggests. Obviously there's limits where you'd negotiate ("all elves are 20 ft tall") but. i don't think anybody's ever played in purely "the reality dnd 4 is in"--even if you're playing published adventures, the table is going to come up with their own little pieces of setting elements.

Comment: To be clear: Stackexchange user "nobody the hobgoblin"s answer is great. accidentally [Outis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outis)'d myself when rereading the comment for typos.

Comment: @Kaia ^^ Thanks for the explanation. And the added message. I hadn't known about Outis. Which is fantastic, because it ties in to the current campaign in a suprising way. My dude double majored as a Bard and went a little extra about it, so he's in a band. The band is called Lorem Ipsum and his bandmate's stage name is <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Smithee" target="_blank">Alan Smithee</a>. My guy has also now found his stage name, thanks to you. Outis. :D
EDIT: clearly I don't know how to work this website. I tried to do a link...

Comment: It uses markdown formatting, so \[text goes here\]\(www.example.com\). :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### These colors are fine

According to the 4e PHB (p. 49) on the Physical Qualities of a Tiefling:

> Their skin color covers the **whole human range and also extends to reds**, from a ruddy tan to a brick red. Their hair, cascading down from behind their horns, is as likely to be dark blue, red, or purple as more common human colors.

So "pale salmon/peach (...) and  (...) low lights that would lean towards a rusty burgundy color" works, burgundry being a kind of red.

Comment: Thank you very much! <3